# erlang dbg module not work when use relx

Tags: erlang, cowboy, dbg, relx

I modified relx.config in a cowboy example,add `runtime_tools`

`{release, {echo_get_example, "1"}, [runtime_tools, echo_get]}.
{extended_start_script, true}.`

when I use dbg:start() -> dbg:tracer() -> ....
nothing outputs when calls then functions.
why?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can actually call the `dbg` module you have most likely succeeded in including it in the release.

Are you connecting with a remote node? In that case, you have to tell `dbg` to trace on the node you're connected to:

```
debugger@localhost> dbg:tracer().
{ok,<0.35.0>}
debugger@localhost> dbg:n(target@host).
{ok,target@host}
debugger@localhost> dbg:p(all, call).
{ok,[{target@host,33},{debugger@localhost,34}]}
debugger@localhost> dbg:tp(...)
```

More details [here](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-July/045001.html) and in [the documentation for `dbg`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html#n-1).

Comment: I'm not in remote node, take cowboy hello_world app for example. I just ran ```~/code/cowboy/examples/hello_world$ ./_rel/hello_world_example/bin/hello_world_example console```  it's my local node,but dbg nothing outputs

Comment: Perhaps you can create [your own tracer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html#id68664)? Instead of the normal printout in that example, try `io:format(user, "~p~n", [Msg])`. That will print out to the local shell for sure. If that works, then something is redirecting your output from the shell to somewhere else.